# 10mm socket fell inside dashboard of 2008 Corolla

Tags: corolla, dashboard

I was opening the radio screws to install an aux adapter for my car. When I was pulling the screwdriver out, the socket bit fell inside the center console. I tried looking inside with a flashlight but I had no success. I have pictures of the interior.[image: You can see the opening here]

Can you guys give me some advice on getting the bit out? 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that happens quite often, there exists a whole set of tools just for this task: The magnetic pick up tool.
[image]

Poke around on the presumed location of the socket and see if you are lucky. Should you have no success fishing it out you will need to disassemble the center console

Comment: Do you suggest a straight one or flexible?

Comment: Both, as it depends where it went. Once you have got bored trying to get it with the mag pickup, just go ahead and remove the console... And next time make sure the socket is firmly attached - we all learn by experience...

Answer (score 0):

Buy a new socket, much cheaper and faster than alternatives.

Comment: Disadvantage is the old one could cause an annoying rattle...

Comment: Yes, that was my motive for retrieving the original. Eitherway, we got the tool and my dad fished it out. Thank you all for your suggestions.